# Android: how to play a video indefinitely

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I need to keep on playing the same video for an indefinite number of times.

I could do:

```
 while(true)    
     VideoView.start();
```

but it looks sick and insane.

I am sure there is somebody with a better suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// video finish listener

        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                            mp.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

just use this code:

```
mp.setOnPreparedListener (new OnPreparedListener() {                    
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setLooping(true);
    }
});
```

use **setLooping** method for more details refer this offical document link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping%28boolean%29